# Join Two Tables Conditioned on a Third Table

Tags: sql, t-sql, subquery, azure-sql-database, inner-join

I am trying to create a view of two tables, based on a condition from a third. I have three tables:

**clients**

```
+-----------+------------+
| client_id | first_name |
+-----------+------------+
|  10000000 | Samantha   |
|  10000001 | Andrew     |
|  10000002 | Audrey     |
+-----------+------------+
```

**addresses**

```
+-----------+------------------+---------------+-----------+
| client_id |    account_id    |    street     |   city    |
+-----------+------------------+---------------+-----------+
|  10000000 | AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA | 123 Apple St  | Brussels  |
|  10000000 | BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB | 111 Orange St | Hong Kong |
|  10000001 | CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC | 456 Grape St  | Amsterdam |
|  10000002 | DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD | 789 Peach St  | Toronto   |
+-----------+------------------+---------------+-----------+
```

**accounts**

```
+-----------+------------------+-----------+
| client_id |    account_id    |  status   |
+-----------+------------------+-----------+
|  10000000 | AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA | cancelled |   <-- i do not want this record
|  10000000 | BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB | active    |
|  10000001 | CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC | active    |
|  10000002 | DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD | active    |
+-----------+------------------+-----------+
```

I am trying to achieve an output that looks like:

```
+-----------+------------+------------------+---------------+-----------+
| client_id | first_name |    account_id    |    street     |   city    |
+-----------+------------+------------------+---------------+-----------+
|  10000000 | Samantha   | BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB | 111 Orange St | Hong Kong |
|  10000001 | Andrew     | CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC | 456 Grape St  | Amsterdam |
|  10000002 | Audrey     | DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD | 789 Peach St  | Toronto   |
+-----------+------------+------------------+---------------+-----------+
```

I'm having trouble pulling the results. I end up with both records for `Samantha`. Here's my latest query effort; what am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT
    ClientTable.client_id,
    ClientTable.first_name,
    AddressTable.account_id,
    AddressTable.street,
    AddressTable.city
FROM
    [clients] ClientTable
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            [addresses].client_id,
            [addresses].account_id,
            [addresses].street,
            [addresses].city
        FROM [addresses]
        INNER JOIN [accounts] ON [addresses].client_id = [accounts].client_id
        WHERE [accounts].status <> 'cancelled'
    ) AddressTable ON ClientTable.client_id = AddressTable.client_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the `clients` and `addresses` tables, and use `not exists` to evict "cancelled" accounts:

```
select cl.client_id, cl.first_name, ad.account_id, ad.street, ad.city
from clients cl
inner join addresses ad on ad.client_id = cl.client_id
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from accounts ac 
    where 
        ac.client_id = ad.client_id 
        and ac.account_id = ad.account_id
        and ac.status = 'cancelled'
)
```

Another approach uses a `join` on `accounts`, as your originally intended to:

```
select cl.client_id, cl.first_name, ad.account_id, ad.street, ad.city
from clients cl
inner join addresses ad on ad.client_id = cl.client_id
inner join accounts ac on ac.client_id = ad.client_id and ac.account_id = ad.account_id
where ac.status <> 'cancelled'
```

Note that both queries do not do exactly the same thing; the second query requires an account with a non-cancelled status, while the first just forbids cancelled account (an address without an account would be allowed).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3bd5f773aa34468115d5ed1a38af97ae)** - both queries yield:

```
client_id | first_name | account_id       | street        | city     
--------: | :--------- | :--------------- | :------------ | :--------
 10000000 | Samantha   | BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB | 111 Orange St | Hong Kong
 10000001 | Andrew     | CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC | 456 Grape St  | Amsterdam
 10000002 | Audrey     | DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD | 789 Peach St  | Toronto
```

Comment: There's an issue with your first approach: `and ac.account_id = cl.account_id`, in that `account_id` is not a column of `cl`. Assuming you meant, `and ac.account_id = cl.account_id`, then I still end up with both records for `Samantha`. Similarly, your second throws an error by trying to compare: `and ac.account_id = ad.client_id`. Assuming you meant `and ac.account_id = ad.account_id`, I still end up with both records for `Samantha`.

Comment: @Crayons: I fixed the aliases. I also added a db fiddle to my answer - Samantha appears just once.

Comment: Sorry @GMB, the mistake is on my part. There are many status', beyond just cancelled. I was forgetting the others. After applying the appropriate `WHERE` clauses against my real world data, both solutions you proposed worked. Kudos for introducing DB Fiddle, I didn't know it existed. Based on my tests, utilizing `WHERE NOT EXISTS` performed better. Cheers mate.